# JavaFx TextArea Prompt Text

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

I am trying to get the `TextArea`'s prompt text to display in a certain format. I am able to achieve the format I want, but it requires me to add lots of white space between text. I was thinking `\n` would do the trick, but it did not. Is there a way to get to the prompt text to go to the next line without `wrapText="true"` and lots of white space?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ez_proxy_2.toolbar_buttons.AddStanzaController">
    <children>
        <StackPane>
            <children>
                <Label alignment="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Title">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="28.0" />
                    </font>
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="10.0" />
                    </padding>
                </Label>
                <FontAwesomeIconView fx:id="faQuestionMark" glyphName="QUESTION_CIRCLE" size="32" StackPane.alignment="CENTER_RIGHT">
                    <StackPane.margin>
                        <Insets right="10.0" />
                    </StackPane.margin>
                </FontAwesomeIconView>
            </children>
        </StackPane>
        <TextField fx:id="tfTitle" alignment="CENTER" promptText="Enter Title Here">
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets left="20.0" right="20.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
        </TextField>
        <Label alignment="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Stanza Info">
            <font>
                <Font size="17.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <TextArea fx:id="taStanzaInfo" promptText="Title Fake Title                                                                                                                                         URL https://www.example.com                                                                                                                     HJ www.example.com                                                                                                                               DJ example.com" wrapText="true">
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets left="20.0" right="20.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
        </TextArea>
        <Button fx:id="btnOff" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBtnOff" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="52.0" text="Off" />
        <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" spacing="10.0">
            <children>
                <Button fx:id="btnExit" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBtnExit" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="52.0" text="Exit" />
                <Button fx:id="btnAdd" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBtnAdd" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="52.0" text="Add" />
            </children>
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets left="20.0" right="20.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
        </HBox>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

[image]

Comment: I’m not in a position to test this, but since an FXML file is XML, you probably will need to use [numeric entities](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-xml-19980210#sec-references) to represent the `\n` character (codepoint 10): `<TextArea fx:id="taStanzaInfo" promptText="Title Fake Title&#10;URL https://www.example.com&#10;HJ www.example.com&#10;DJ example.com" wrapText="true">`.  However, XML attribute normalization may turn each newline into a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using XML syntax for `\r\n` - `&#13;&#10;` (in my test example, for some reason, just `&#10;` doesn't work for `promptText` attribute, but it works fine with `text`):

```
<TextArea promptText="Title Fake Title&#13;&#10;URL https://www.example.com&#13;&#10;HJ www.example.com&#13;&#10;DJ example.comButton" />
```

[image]